# Accessing Swagger through Spring API Gateway

Tags: java, http, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a microservice(user service) running at localhost:8080, a gateway on localhost:8765 and a routing configuration as

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRouter(RouteLocatorBuilder routeLocatorBuilder){
    return routeLocatorBuilder
            .routes()
            .route(predicateSpec -> predicateSpec
                            .path("/user-service/**")
                            .filters(
                                    gatewayFilterSpec -> gatewayFilterSpec
                                            .rewritePath("/user-service/(?<segment>.*)", "/${segment}")
                            )
                            .uri("lb://USER-SERVICE")
            )
            .route(predicateSpec -> predicateSpec
                    .path("/location-service/**")
                    .filters(
                            gatewayFilterSpec -> gatewayFilterSpec
                                    .rewritePath("/location-service/(?<segment>.*)", "/${segment}")
                    )
                    .uri("lb://LOCATION-SERVICE")
            )
            .build();
}
```

on localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html it redirects to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html#/ and I am able to access the swagger all good till here but through API gateway when I make a request the redirect happens on the API gateway. Redirects to **http://localhost:8765/swagger-ui/index.html**

[1st request and response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYeIc.png)
[2nd request(redirect) headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN3K4.png)

how to make the location response locate in user service or redirect in user service and return HTML as a response.